# How to search file inside a specific folder in google API v3

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api

As i am using v3 of google api,So instead of using parent and chidren list i have to use fileList, So now i want to search list of file inside a specific folder.
So someone can suggest me what to do?

Here is the code i am using to search the file :

```
private String searchFile(String mimeType,String fileName) throws IOException{
    Drive driveService = getDriveService();
    String fileId = null;
    String pageToken = null;
    do {
        FileList result = driveService.files().list()
                .setQ(mimeType)
                .setSpaces("drive")
                .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
                .setPageToken(pageToken)
                .execute();
        for(File f: result.getFiles()) {
            System.out.printf("Found file: %s (%s)\n",
                    f.getName(), f.getId());
            if(f.getName().equals(fileName)){
                //fileFlag++;
                fileId = f.getId();
            }
        }
        pageToken = result.getNextPageToken();
    } while (pageToken != null);

    return fileId;
}
```

But in this method it giving me all the files that are generated which i don't want.I want to create a FileList which will give file inside a specific folder.

Answer (score 13):

It is now possible to do it with the term `parents` in `q` parameter in `drives:list`. For example, if you want to find all spreadsheets in a folder with id `folder_id` you can do so using the following `q` parameter (I am using python in my example):

```
q="mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' and parents in '{}'".format(folder_id)
```

Remember that you should find out the id of the folder files inside of which you are looking for. You can do this using the same `drives:list`.

More information on `drives:list` method can be seen [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/list), and you can read more about other terms you can put to `q` parameter [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms).

Answer (score 8):

To search in a specific directory you have to specify the following:

```
q : name = '2021' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and '1fJ9TFZOe8G9PUMfC2Ts06sRnEPJQo7zG' in parents
```

This examples search a folder called "2021" into folder with 1fJ9TFZOe8G9PUMfC2Ts06sRnEPJQo7zG

In my case, I'm writing a code in c++ and the request url would be:

```
string url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=name+%3d+%272021%27+and+mimeType+%3d+%27application/vnd.google-apps.folder%27+and+trashed+%3d+false+and+%271fJ9TFZOe8G9PUMfC2Ts06sRnEPJQo7zG%27+in+parents";
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching files by folder name is not yet supported. It's been requested in this [google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/vEPW91FtIP8) but so far, nothing yet. However, try to look for other alternative search filters available in [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters).

Be creative. For example make sure the files within a certain folder contains a unique keyword which you can then query using

```
 fullText contains 'my_unique_keyword'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to search the files from google drive:

```
Files.List request = this.driveService.files().list();
noOfRecords = 100;
request.setPageSize(noOfRecords);
request.setPageToken(nextPageToken);
String searchQuery = "(name contains 'Hello')";
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(searchQuery)) {
    request.setQ(searchQuery);
}
request.execute();
```

Comment: this is generic searching of files, and not "search file within a specific folder name".