# how to determine number of files in a folder in Grive or list them by date ascending

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I'm using the Gdrive Java API and the code I have to list a directory is:

```
FileList result = driveService.files().list() 
            .setPageSize(100)
            .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name, parents)")
            .execute();
```

However, this assumes there are no more than 100 files in the folder.. how can I list all of them? How can I search a folder for a file? How can I list only the top 100 most recent ones?

Comment: if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76543524/17926478) answer actually worked for you (at least for your initial concern), don't forget to either upvote or mark it as 'best answer'. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more than 100 files, then you can update `setPageSize(100)` to `setPageSize(1000)` which is the maximum number of items returned in the list request (didn't find this information in documentation but I tested this and confirmed it allows up to 1000).

If you have more than 1000 files and want to list all of them then you will need to iterate on the `list().execute()` and include the `nextPageToken` in your request, until `nextPageToken` returns `null`.

I guess in your question `How can I search a folder for a file?` you are referring to how to search for a file in a folder, if this is not the case please clarify. In case you're trying to search for a file in a folder, then you can add a query to your request. ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45455886/17926478) is a sample on how to make the request with a query)

```java
String searchQuery = "name contains 'nameOfFile' and mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and 'folderID' in parents"
```

And for your last question, you can add the `orderBy` parameter in your request and use a valid key like `createdTime` or `modifiedTime`.

> `orderBy` A comma-separated list of sort keys. Valid keys are 'createdTime', 'folder', 'modifiedByMeTime', 'modifiedTime', 'name', 'name_natural', 'quotaBytesUsed', 'recency', 'sharedWithMeTime', 'starred', and 'viewedByMeTime'. Each key sorts ascending by default, but can be reversed with the 'desc' modifier. Example usage: ?orderBy=folder,modifiedTime desc,name.

#### References:

- [Query string samples](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files#examples)
- [Query parameters](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/list?apix_params=%7B%22corpora%22%3A%22user%22%2C%22q%22%3A%22createdTime%20%3E%20%272022-03-10T19%3A17%3A38.565Z%27%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22files%20(*)%22%7D#query-parameters)